# python socketserver opening files from webpage

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to make a small server that runs on local machines that will get a request from a webpage and open up a file in openoffice. This approach so far works. However, there are times when requests will not come through right away. When this happens I will wait for at least 5 seconds and then try to hit it a couple more times and then all of the requests come in at the same time. I would really like this to be reliable. Is there something I am missing that will stop this from happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also I am aware that the way I am doing things may not be the safest. I am trying to make it functional and then will work on making it more secure.

```
import SocketServer
import subprocess
import time


class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
        print self.data

        try:
            if self.data != '':
                st = self.data.split('\n', 1)[0]
                #print st
                st = st.split(' ')[1]
                print st
                if ".odt" in st:
                    p = subprocess.Popen('C:\openoffice\program\swriter.exe "'+st[1:]+'"')
                    time.sleep(1)
                    p.terminate()
        except Exception as err:
            print err
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.wfile.write(self.data.upper())

PORT = 8081
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyTCPHandler)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```